# how to block facebook in mac

Tags: facebook

i'm looking for a way to block facebook in my computer. I edited the host file to 127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com and it worked fine but, now i noticed that i'm still able to log into facebook through http://sv-se.facebook.com is there a way i can block this last one ?

Comment: You can do the same to `sv-se.facebook.com` that you did to `www.facebook.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are blocking entire Facebook, add the following to the host file. I recommend pointing them to 169.28.5.13 however.

127.0.0.1  www.facebook.com

127.0.0.1  facebook.com

127.0.0.1  static.ak.fbcdn.net

127.0.0.1  www.static.ak.fbcdn.net

127.0.0.1  login.facebook.com

127.0.0.1  www.login.facebook.com

127.0.0.1  www.sv-se.facebook.com

127.0.0.1  sv-se.facebook.com

127.0.0.1  fbcdn.net

127.0.0.1  www.fbcdn.net

127.0.0.1  fbcdn.com

127.0.0.1  www.fbcdn.com

127.0.0.1  static.ak.connect.facebook.com

127.0.0.1  www.static.ak.connect.facebook.com

Comment: wow that's a lot of addresses. They've really found their way arround. Can you provide links for youtube and twitter as well? And why should i point them to 169.28.5.13 instead of 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: 169.28.5.13 is a non existent address, where as I'd run an httpd off my computer and it would point to that. It's not a huge issue but a lot better. I am not sure on all of YouTubes, I have just had to block Facebook from work.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the domain without the www. prefix:

```
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 facebook.com
```